# Display custom error message in ajax over HTTP/2

Tags: ajax, http2

In my MVC application, I have used Ajax's Response.StatusText to display custom error messages to user whenever there is some error.It works fine but when I deploy my application on AWS, the StatusText gets removed and only the code is displayed. Got to know that because of using HTTP/2, the statusText gets removed.

Is there a way to show custom error message in Ajax error over HTTP/2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the HTTP Status is the best place to put these. You should either put this status in the body, or possibly in a custom HTTP header.

Comment: Okay. Will go for it. Thanks.